# Kivy: 'NoneType' object is not callable, on button deleting

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to code in Python with Kivy a simple interface, with 4 elements: a title bar at the top, a text-input at the bottom and next to it a little button "add". Between the top and the bottom I want a scroll view, and when we click on the button next to the text-input, it creates a new button in the scrollview, and next to it a little button to delete the line (line = the button + its delete button)
To understand:
[image: what i want]

When I click on the "X" button to delete, I have an error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "nouv_test.py", line 39, in <module>
     RunApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\dvfrg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 828, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Users\dvfrg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\dvfrg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 663, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\dvfrg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 405, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "C:\Users\dvfrg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 342, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "C:\Users\dvfrg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 327, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "C:\Users\dvfrg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 233, in post_dispatch_input
     listener.dispatch('on_motion', etype, me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:8191)
   File "C:\Users\dvfrg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1192, in on_motion
     self.dispatch('on_touch_up', me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:8191)
   File "C:\Users\dvfrg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1228, in on_touch_up
     if w.dispatch('on_touch_up', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:8191)
   File "C:\Users\dvfrg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 1199, in on_touch_up
     return super(ScreenManager, self).on_touch_up(touch)
   File "C:\Users\dvfrg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 479, in on_touch_up
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_up', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:8191)
   File "C:\Users\dvfrg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\relativelayout.py", line 304, in on_touch_up
     ret = super(RelativeLayout, self).on_touch_up(touch)
   File "C:\Users\dvfrg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 479, in on_touch_up
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_up', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:8191)
   File "C:\Users\dvfrg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 479, in on_touch_up
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_up', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:8191)
   File "C:\Users\dvfrg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\scrollview.py", line 833, in on_touch_up
     if self.dispatch('on_scroll_stop', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:8191)
   File "C:\Users\dvfrg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\scrollview.py", line 872, in on_scroll_stop
     self.simulate_touch_down(touch)
   File "C:\Users\dvfrg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\scrollview.py", line 596, in simulate_touch_down
     ret = super(ScrollView, self).on_touch_down(touch)
   File "C:\Users\dvfrg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 457, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:8191)
   File "C:\Users\dvfrg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 457, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:8191)
   File "C:\Users\dvfrg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 151, in on_touch_down
     self.dispatch('on_press')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:8191)
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

**Here are my code (.py / .kv):**

```
# coding: utf-8

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder


from kivy.uix.button import Button


class GUI(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GUI, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class Home(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Home, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def add_btn(self, grid):
        left = Button(text="added", size = (32, 32), size_hint = (1, None)) # the green button
        right = Button(background_color = (1,0,0,1), text="X", size = (32, 32), size_hint = (None, None)) # the red DELETE button

        right.on_press = self.del_btn(grid, left, right)

        grid.add_widget(left)
        grid.add_widget(right)

    def del_btn(self, grid, L, R): # function called when I click on delete a line
        grid.remove_widget(L)
        grid.remove_widget(R)

Builder.load_file("nouv_test.kv")

class RunApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return GUI()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    RunApp().run()
```

.KV:

```
 #: kivy 1.10.0

    <GUI>:
        Home:
            name: "home_screen"
            id: home

    <Home>:

        GridLayout:
            rows: 3

            Button:
                text: u"Mes ann\u00e9es"
                size: (50, 50)
                size_hint: (1, None)
                background_color: (0,1,0,1)

            ScrollView:


                size_hint:(1, .8)
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
                do_scroll_x: False

                GridLayout:
                    id: home_scroll_grid
                    cols: 2
                    padding: 5
                    spacing: 5
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    size_hint: (1, None)


            BoxLayout:

                padding: 5
                spacing: 5
                size: (42, 42)
                size_hint: (1, None)

                TextInput:
                    size: (32, 32)
                    size_hint: (1, None)

                Button:
                    text: "+"
                    background_color: (0,1,0,1)
                    size: (32, 32)
                    size_hint: (None, None)
                    on_press: root.add_btn(home_scroll_grid)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a `NoneType` error, because in this statement: `right.on_press = self.del_btn(grid, left, right)`, you actually called `del_btn`, and it returns nothing.
`on_press` takes a callable, not a called function. So it should rather look like this: `right.on_press = self.del_btn`.

But since you need to pass arguments to your callback, you can use `partial`.
And then use `.bind` instead of assigning to on_press.
Like this:

```python
from functools import partial
```

Then:

```python
right.bind(on_press=partial(self.del_btn, grid, left, right))
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I imported partial and used "bind" as you said, there is no error anymore. However, when I click on the delete button, nothing happens...

Comment: EDIT: We forgot "grid" parameter in `on_press=partial(self.def_btn, grid, left, right)`. My problem is solved, thank you !

Comment: @MikeDelta ah yes, sorry. I will edit the answer.. You are wellcome.